# Pure JS and Regex to get first datetime

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to get the first datetime received here:

```
{ Start: '2019-10-22T15:00:00Z', End: '2019-10-22T15:30:00Z' }
```

Here is what I am trying:

```
var srctextsch = { Start: '2019-10-22T15:00:00Z', End: '2019-10-22T15:30:00Z' };
var srctext ="'"+srctextsch+"'"; 
console.log("old text: " + srctext);

//var re = /.*cow\s+(.*)\s+milk.*/;
var re = /.*{ Start: '(.*?)\', End: '(.*?)\' }/;
var newtext = srctext.replace(re, "$1");
console.log(newtext);
```

If I remove the first variable "srctextsch" and add the value to the "srctext" variable like so:

```
var srctext = "{ Start: '2019-10-22T15:00:00Z', End: '2019-10-22T15:30:00Z' }";
```

Then I can get what I need: 2019-10-22T15:00:00Z

If I don't add the quotes then I get "Uncaught TypeError: srctext.replace is not a function"

```
var srctext = { Start: '2019-10-22T15:00:00Z', End: '2019-10-22T15:30:00Z' };
```

If I attempt to hack quotes into the variable value like so:

```
var srctextsch = { Start: '2019-10-22T15:00:00Z', End: '2019-10-22T15:30:00Z' };
    var srctext ="'"+srctextsch+"'";
```

Then I get [object], [obeject]

What am I missing???

Comment: why in the world are you not just parsing as JSON then extracting your timestamp? `JSON.parse(srctextsch).Start` is all you need

Comment: If `srctext` is already a js object you can just do `srctext.Start`

Comment: Given your date-time strings are ISO 8601 formatted, you can get real `Date` objects using `new Date(srctextsch.Start)`

Comment: @DanO unfortunately what is being returned is not properly formatted JSON. So when I run this: JSON.parse(srctextsch).Start i get this: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: @Phil Your answer worked! Thanks!!!